# How do I install Redis and the phpredis extension in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, redis, phpredis

The Laravel documentation [recommends](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/redis#introduction) using the [`phpredis`](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis) PHP extension instead of the `predis` package due to having better performance, which PHP extensions generally seem to at the cost of a more complicated setup. Unfortunately the documentation is thin on the actual process of installing this extension, or resources to doing so.

Like all PHP extensions `phpredis` is not available in Composer - how do I install it on my server?

Answer (score 0):

## For XAMPP servers

1. Install a **thread-safe** version of `phpredis` from [here](https://pecl.php.net/package/redis)  by following the Windows DLL links for your desired version and scrolling down.
2. Extract the downloaded ZIP and copy the `.dll` file in it to `C:\XAMPP\php\ext`.
3. Restart the Apache server, then from a command-line run `php -m` and look for `redis` in the output to confirm that the `phpredis` extension is being loaded.
4. Bizarrely, Redis has [no official Windows release](https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/12086) despite being the most widely used OS for development servers by a large margin. This leaves us having to trust one of the many third-party binaries out there. The most reputable of these and the most likely to still be around in the future seems to be [Memurai](https://www.memurai.com/get-memurai), which is an enterprise product that is free for development use - this is fine for our needs because no-one should be running a production server on XAMPP. Installing the free version of Memurai will automatically add a Windows service to start the Redis server with your PC.
5. To test that your Redis connection is working, run the following commands from a Cygwin/WSL/CMD terminal:

   ```
   $ memurai.exe
   // Start the Memurai Redis server
   $ ping
   // Should output PONG
   $ set test "It's alive"
   // Should output OK
   ```
6. Finally, to test whether the data you set above has been persisted, restart your PC and run the following commands:

   ```
   $ memurai.exe
   $ get test
   // Should output "It's alive"
   $ del test // Delete the test key to tidy up
   ```

Answer (score 0):

## For Ubuntu and Debian servers

1. Use your distro's package manager to install the `phpredis` extension, replacing 8.1 with the version of PHP that your server is running (run `php -v` to check):

   ```
   apt-get install php_redis8.1
   ```
2. Run `php -m` and look for `redis` in the list of extensions to confirm that the `phpredis` extension is being loaded.
3. Install the Redis server and CLI by running the following command (copy-paste and enter to run the whole thing at once) and following the instructions:

   ```
   curl -fsSL https://packages.redis.io/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/redis-archive-keyring.gpg &&
   echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/redis-archive-keyring.gpg] https://packages.redis.io/deb $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/redis.list &&
   sudo apt update &&
   sudo apt install redis-server
   ```
4. Once the Redis server and CLI have been installed, open the Redis config file with

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/redis/redis.conf
   ```

   ...and look for the `supervised` option - change it from `no` to `systemd`:

   ```
   # /etc/redis/redis.conf
   supervised systemd
   ```
5. Restart the `redis` service to make this configuration change take effect:

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart redis.service
   ```
6. To test that Redis is installed and running correctly, run the following commands:

   ```
   $ redis-cli
   // Start the Redis CLI
   $ ping
   // Should output PONG
   $ set test "It's alive"
   // Should output OK
   ```
7. Finally, to test whether the data you set above has been persisted, run the following commands:

   ```
   $ exit
   $ sudo systemctl restart redis
   $ redis-cli 
   $ get test
   // Should output "It's alive"
   $ del test // Delete the test key to tidy up
   ```

You now have Redis server installed on your server and successfully using the `phpredis` extension as recommended by Laravel.

[See here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-redis-on-ubuntu-22-04) for more detailed instructions to this process, as well as how to configure a password to Redis for additional security (newer versions of Redis already bind the server to localhost by default, so this usually isn't necessary to do).